# How to read file from HTTPRequest on a dart:io server

Tags: dart, dart-io

I am trying to create a server to run locally for my application to upload some files while debugging. It is very simple and the full source code is:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  const port = 8080;
  final server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port);
  server.listen((request) async {
    if (request.uri.path != '/save_screenshot' || request.method != 'POST') {
      request.response.statusCode = 404;
      request.response.close();
      return;
    }

    // TODO: read the file
    request.response.statusCode = 200;
    request.response.close();
  });
  print('screenshot server listening on $port.');
}
```

At the code there is a TODO comment, where I would like to read the file from the HTTPRequest, I googled a bit and could not find a example to copy. Does anyone know how to read the file from the HTTPRequest?

Here is how it is being sent (on the client side):

```dart
final url = 'http://<local_ip_address>:8080/save_screenshot';
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.files.add(
  http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'file',
    screenshot.bytes,
    filename: 'screenshot.png',
  ),
);
await request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to read the file from the HTTPRequest. But for it to work it is necessary to install a package called `mime`.

Then replace the TODO comment in the question with:

```dart
final boundary = request.headers.contentType!.parameters['boundary']!;
final mimeTransformer = MimeMultipartTransformer(boundary);
final parts = request.cast<List<int>>().transform(mimeTransformer);
await for (final part in parts) {
  final file = File('uploaded_files/0.png');
  await part.pipe(file.openWrite());
}
```

I made a gist with the working server: https://gist.github.com/lslv1243/1036364b10c6578d969cb4ed2d7eba42

NOTE: on the gist I changed the path from `/save_screenshot` to `/screenshot`

Comment: I got this error:
` FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'uploaded_files/0.png' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.`
How to solve it?

Comment: I send image from the flutter app to dart server API by using 
`
        request.files.add(
          http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            file.key,
            file.value,
            contentType: MediaType('images', 'jpeg'),
            filename: fileName,
          ),
        );
`
`file.value` is bytes (List<int>)

Comment: Maybe the folder does not exist. Make sure the path where you are running `dart` from has the folder. It is possible to create it when creating the file if it does not exist, using `file.create(recursive: true)` before writing to it.

Comment: Thank you. This `file.create(recursive: true)` work. But my `0.png` file is empty(0 bytes). How to get the file that was sent from my flutter app? (For the PHP server the file will appear in `$_FILES[file.key]`. The `file.key` from 
`request.files.add( http.MultipartFile.fromBytes( file.key, file.value, contentType: MediaType('images', 'jpeg'), filename: fileName, ), );` 
in the flutter app)

Comment: Hi, I found the `shelf` package and I can receive and upload files.